# sleekxmpp send message to all the resource with same user name

Tags: python-2.7, xmpp

I am trying to send a message from user-B to all the resources logged in with username user-A. But only the first resource alone that was logged in is getting the message. This is similar to presence being broadcast to all the resources within a user. Is there a way to do this using sleek-xmpp?

I tried using send_message

```
        self.send_message(mto='userA@testserver',
                      mbody='sending - chat message ',
                      mtype='chat')
```

But it is received by only the first resource that was logged in .

The server that I am using is Openfire .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the sender, nor the sender's server, but the recipient's server that controls which of the recipient's resources receive a message with `type='chat'`. Typically, this is based on the priority of the presences set by the recipient's resources.

There are some workarounds, though:

- Use a `type='headline'` message (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-5.2.2):

  > If the 'to' address is the bare JID, the receiving server SHOULD deliver the message to all of the recipient's available resources with non-negative presence priority and MUST deliver the message to at least one of those resources;
- Ask the recipient to use clients that support [XEP-0280](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html). This allows clients to opt-in to receiving every chat message.
- If you have a subscription to the recipient's presence, you can send a separate message to each resource, but that's a very bad idea in many regards (one of them: it can cause duplicates in the offline storage if some resources went offline in the mean time).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the option 1 - "headline" as well as xep-0280 . But it din't work. Only one of resource is getting the message.